# Doctrine Fixtures doesn't get persisted, why?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a small set of Doctrine DataFixtures which is setup as follow:

```sh
$ tree -A code/src/AppBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/
code/src/AppBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/
├── LoadCategoryData.php
├── LoadCategoryHasPostData.php
└── LoadPostData.php
```

See the following output when I try to load the fixtures:

```sh
$ docker exec -u www-data -it coding_webserver_1 php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load -vvv
Careful, database will be purged. Do you want to continue y/N ?y
  > purging database
  > loading [1] AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadCategoryData
  > loading [2] AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadPostData
  > loading [3] AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadCategoryHasPostData


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]                                                                                                                                                         
  Type error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Entity\CategoryHasPosts::setCategory() must be an instance of AppBundle\Entity\Category, null given, called in /var/www/src/AppBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/LoadCategory  
  HasPostData.php on line 22
```

This is how the file `LoadCategoryData` looks like:

```php
class LoadCategoryData extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $category_1 = new Category();
        $category_1->setCategoryName('Hot');
        $category_1->setCategoryDescription('Hot Topics');
        $category_1->setSlug('hot');
        $category_1->setActive(true);
        $manager->persist($category_1);

        $category_2 = new Category();
        $category_2->setCategoryName('New');
        $category_2->setCategoryDescription('New Topics');
        $category_2->setSlug('new');
        $category_2->setActive(true);
        $manager->persist($category_2);

        $manager->flush();
    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

This is the content of `LoadPostData` file:

```php
class LoadPostData extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $faker = Faker\Factory::create();

        for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
            $post = new Post();
            $post->setPostTitle($faker->sentence);
            $post->setPostContent($faker->paragraph);
            $post->setSlug($faker->slug);

            $manager->persist($post);
        }

        $manager->flush();
    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

And this is the content of `LoadCategoryHasPostData` file:

```php
class LoadCategoryHasPostData extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 2000; $i++) {
            $category_id = random_int(1, 2);
            $category    = $manager->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->find($category_id);

            $post_id = random_int(1, 2000);
            $post    = $manager->getRepository('AppBundle:Post')->find($post_id);

            $categoryHasPost = new CategoryHasPosts();
            $categoryHasPost->setCategory($category);
            $categoryHasPost->setPost($post);

            $manager->persist($categoryHasPost);
        }

        $manager->flush();
    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

I know why the process is failing and it's logic: the previous entities weren't persisted and this is my why goes to.

Why `Category` and `Post` weren't persisted and flushed? What I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use *references* to [share entities between fixtures](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#sharing-objects-between-fixtures):

```
class LoadCategoryData extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $category_1 = new Category();
        // …
        $manager->persist($category_1);
        $this->addReference('category_1', $category_1);

        $manager->flush();
    }
    // …
}
```

```php
class LoadPostData extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $faker = Faker\Factory::create();

        for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
            $post = new Post();
            $post->setPostTitle($faker->sentence);
            $post->setPostContent($faker->paragraph);
            $post->setSlug($faker->slug);

            $manager->persist($post);
            $this->addReference('post_' . $i, $post);
        }

        $manager->flush();
    }
    // …
}
```

```php
class LoadCategoryHasPostData extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $categoryHasPost = new CategoryHasPosts();
        $categoryHasPost->setCategory($this->getReference('category_1'));
        $categoryHasPost->setPost($this->getReference('post_1'));

        $manager->persist($categoryHasPost);

        $manager->flush();
    }
    // …
}
```

Comment: I know but I don't know how to set the reference when there is more than one variable, could you add an example using post instead?

Comment: @ReynierPM I've updated answer according your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```php
class LoadCategoryHasPostData extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface {
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $categories = $manager->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->findAll();

        $posts = $manager->getRepository('AppBundle:Post')->findAll();

        for ($i = 0; $i < 2000; $i++) {
            $category = $categories[random_int(0, count($categories) - 1)];
            $post     = $posts[random_int(0, count($posts) - 1);

            $categoryHasPost = new CategoryHasPosts();
            $categoryHasPost->setCategory($category);
            $categoryHasPost->setPost($post);

            $manager->persist($categoryHasPost);
        }

        $manager->flush();
    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I am not seeing where the problem was exactly, can you edit and explain a little bit?

Comment: Each time creating fixtures database purge but ID incremented. `$category_id = random_int(1, 2);` 
Not sure what You have in database have ID 1 or 2.

`/** @return Category|null */
$category = $manager->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->find($category_id); `
This return AppBundle:Category or NULL.
`$categoryHasPost->setCategory($category);`
Type error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Entity\CategoryHasPosts::setCategory() must be an instance of AppBundle\Entity\Category, null given, called in /var/www/src/AppBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/LoadCategory HasPostData.php on line 22